# Share: I made some timer in python 3 ! Here it is:

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

So, below this sentence, there will be code (feel free to copy and paste to change it):

```
# Step 1
import time
import winsound
import datetime
from time import sleep

# Step 2
def sleep_days(days):
    sleep(days * 86400)

def sleep_weeks(weeks):
    sleep(weeks * 604800)

def sleep_years(years):
    sleep(years * 31536000)

def sleep_months(months):
    sleep(months * 2628000)

def sleep_leap_years(leap_years):
    sleep(leap_years * 31622400 )
    
def sleep_minutes(minutes):
    sleep(minutes * 60)

def sleep_hours(hours):
    sleep(hours * 3600)

def Time(Time):
    print(time.time())

# Step 3
i = str(input("Do you want to see the time right now? (y or n) > "))

if (i == 'y'):
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
else:
    print("")

# Step 4
a = int(input("Enter how many times I have beep when i'm done  > "))
b = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Years) > "))
c = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Months) > "))
d = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Weeks) > "))
e = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Days) > "))
f = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Hours) > "))
g = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Minutes) > "))
h = int(input("Enter when to beep (in Seconds) > "))

# Step 5
sleep_years(b)
sleep_months(c)
sleep_weeks(d)
sleep_days(e)
sleep_hours(f)
sleep_minutes(g)
time.sleep(h)

# Step 6
for i in range(a):
    winsound.Beep(3000,100)
    winsound.Beep(2500,100)
    winsound.Beep(2000,100)    
    winsound.Beep(1000,100)    
    winsound.Beep(500,100)
    winsound.Beep(2000,100)
    winsound.Beep(800, 90)

# Step 7
print('DONE')
```

What did I say? It took 2 days to do this. I mostly spent time planning what it would be and do. It just took 30 minutes to write it. it would be nice to have some feedback on how it is. Please comment below what you like, dislike and suggestions. Also, It would be nice if you can leave behind a vote. Thank you!

Comment: Cool program ! Here are a few comments:
It seems like your input does not fit what it is doing (i.e. Enter when to beep in minutes is assigned to hours, etc).
Winsound is really only specific to windows, so your program would not work on other platforms.

Comment: Your Time function is not following the naming convention of the other funtions. It should not have a name that looks like a class, and should most likely not take any argument (since you are not using any in the function). 
You are importing `time` and `time.sleep` and using both. You should only use one of them, i.e. remove `import time` and replace `time.sleep(1)` in step 5 by `sleep(1)`.
I would make the code easier to read if you had a function "beep" that contains your alarm sound (the 7 winsound.Beep)